# Aggregating variables by two other variables in R using pivot_wider

Tags: r, aggregation, dplyr

I have data on cancer case counts in R that I would like to pivot from long to wide, such that a new count variable is created for each five-year age group within race/ethnicity groups. I have tried using dplyr's pivot_wider() function for this, but it gives me a lot of missing values that keep the data longer than I would like. Here is my coding attempt so far:

```
SEER_data_cases <- pivot_wider(data = SEER_data,
                           names_from = age_grp,
                           names_prefix = "cases_",
                           values_from = Count
                           )
```

"SEER_data" is the long data set that I want to pivot wider. "Count" is the variable in SEER_data for the number of observed cancer cases that I would like to be grouped within age group ("age_grp") within race/ethnicity group ("race_eth").

I have attached a screenshot of the long SEER_data data set and the imperfect result of my code that contains a bunch of NA values for each age group variable.

[image: SEER_data long, not yet put into age groups]

[image: My imperfect attempt at aggregating the data by age group]

Comment: share your data using `dput(head(SEER_data, 10))`. This way we don't need to type your data in manually and we are sure that we have the same classes and structure.

Comment: I think you want to summarise by group, not reshape. Search for that and see if that helps.